# jQuery Selector выдает ошибку при попытке выбрать контент для скрытия по классу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать сортировщик выводимого контента нажатием на кнопки с классом `.date`, соответственно в один момент может быть активна только одна кнопка `(jQuery(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");)` эта часть кода работает отлично. У каждой кнопки id представляет собой дату (строчку) и соответствует дополнительному классу контента и я пытаюсь за счет `is/not hasClass` пробежаться по объектам и скрыть не содержащие такой класс объекты.

А вот часть скрывающая и показывающая не работает на сайте, выдавая ошибку - `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .` или `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).is(...).addClass is not a function` если пытаюсь сделать идентификацию через ID.

```
jQuery(".widget").ready(function(){
     jQuery(".date").click(function(){
     jQuery(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
     var dclass = "";
     dclass = this.id;
     jQuery(".timeslot_column").not("." + dclass).addClass("off");
     jQuery(".timeslot_column").is("." + dclass).removeClass("off");
});
});
```

На http://jsfiddle.net/eucyrfbj/43/ делал прототип и все работало без проблем и ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не понимаю, что мне с этим делать, WP подгружает jquery без дополнительного вызова, так что вставить куда-либо повторный вызов не получится.

Comment: @LeoM. Я показал Вам, что ошибка вызвана пустым `this.id`. Почему оно пустое мне неизвестно.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно, буду искать, как правильно присвоить id или другой атрибут присвоить переменной, подставил alert, чтобы проверить значение и действительно переменная пустая

Comment: @LeoM. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибку нашел, но теперь не запускает ' jQuery(".timeslot_column").is("." + dclass).removeClass("off"); ' но ошибок не выдает

Comment: Все, и это победил, огромное спасибо за помощь!